# Change CSS "display: none;" to shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, display

I want an element on my website hidden when the website loads, but when a user submits a form, then it changes to show. I have tried for hours now, can't get it to work.

Code:

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="show();">
<div id="mymessage" class="hidden">Message was sent.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function show () {
  document.getElementById("mymessage").style.display = 'block';
}
```

**Disclaimer: I only included relevant code.**

Hope somebody is able to help me/spot the error!

Comment: how you are submitting form? using form action or ajax?

Comment: @Dinesh I am submitting with PHP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would remove the `hidden` class:

```
function show () {
  document.getElementById("mymessage").classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

(`classList` has very broad support, and can be polyfilled on obsolete browsers if necessary.)

Live Example (using a button click instead of a form submit):

```js
function show () {
  document.getElementById("mymessage").classList.remove("hidden");
  return false;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="mymessage" class="hidden">Message was sent.</div>
<input type="button" onclick="show();" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

You have to return false to prevent the browser from refreshing the page so that you can hide the element on submit:

```js
function show () {
  document.getElementById("mymessage").style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return show();">


<button>enviar</button>
</form>
<div id="mymessage" class="hidden">Message was sent.</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I need to submit the form with PHP, but I have `sleep(20);` in my PHP code, so the message will display for 20 seconds, so I need it to submit EDIT: Sorry I didn't include that piece of information in my main post

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a solution

```
document.getElementById("mymessage").classList.remove("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you use jQuery instead?

```
</script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(){
            jQuery('#mymessage').show();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Remember to add the library above the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: I thought about that, but haven't looked too much into jQuery yet (I mostly use vanilla JavaScript). Thanks for the advice, will keep it for future reference